# sql server function does not allow return statement

Tags: sql-server, function, return

I am trying to create a function in sql server but it keeps telling me :
A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

I have many other functions and they all end with return @variable.
So I must be doing something wrong here and I just can't see it.

Hopefully someone can spot what I am doing wrong here so I can get the function compiling and can complete it.

```
CREATE function fnGetToInvoiceLoads (@TruckID int, @ClientID int, @OpdrachtID int, @OpcID int, @VertrekIDs varchar(max), @BestemmingIDs varchar(max), @CarIDs varchar(max)) 
returns table 
as
begin
    declare @Table  table( RitChecked bit,
                           RitID int, 
                           ClientID int
                          ) 

    return @Table
end
```

Comment: What do you want to achive? you give many parameters to the function but only a few are in your result set? I think what you're looking for is a multi-statement function.

Comment: What I want to achive is to get this function to compile so I can start completing it (like I said in the question). All the parameters will get their use once I can compile the function, That code is all left out here to make the question more simple

Comment: See my answer. You still need the logic but that's your part anyway.

Comment: what is this, an old post, already answered and now some hater comes along and downvotes witthout leaving a reason ? Stack overflow is becoming less interesting lately with all these haters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example... You still need to add your logic to it. But it should give you a hint.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetToInvoiceLoads (@TruckID int, @ClientID int, @OpdrachtID int, @OpcID int, @VertrekIDs varchar(max), @BestemmingIDs varchar(max), @CarIDs varchar(max)) 
RETURNS @result 
    TABLE (RitChecked bit, RitID int, ClientID int)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do your stuff....

    INSERT @result(RitChecked, RitID, ClientID)
        SELECT ....

   RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: I will try this but even if this works I still wonder why I have to write RETURN here without variable and in other functions I have to write RETURN with a variable ? Example 
CREATE function fnGetRitPlaatsen (#RitID int, #IncludeLaadPlaatsen bit, #IncludeLosPlaatsen bit) returns varchar(4000) as
begin
    declare #Result varchar(4000)
    -- code to fill #Result left out here to simplify comment
    return #Result
end
this compiles just fine (at symbol replace by # because it has special meaning in the comment here apparently)

Comment: You define the RETURNS in the function header. If you write return it will just execute the return you've already defined in your function header at this time.

Comment: Now I have another problem. After creating the function sql server cannot find it. I can create it, I can drop it, but I cannot execute it and it also does not shows up in the list of functions like all the other functions I created.

Comment: In which database do you execute the script? Maybe in master? ;-) 
Try use [YourDB] in the head before creating the function.
Maybe you forget the dbo. in your excecution or filtered your management studio to another schema?

Comment: I have use mydb in my script and I have dbo. in my create script and in my select statement, still does not works. The create works, the drop works, but the select said : Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.fnGetToInvoiceLoads", or the name is ambiguous.

Comment: The error with "cannot find column dbo" makes me curios. Can you provide me the SELECT statement? This is a tabled valued functions. This means you should use it in the from part of your select, not in the select - if you need the select part you need a scalar function.

Comment: select dbo.fnGetToInvoiceLoads (null, null, null, null, null, null, null)

Comment: forget it, it works now forget the * from in the select. Correct way is select * from dbo.fnGetToInvoiceLoads(null, null, null, null, null, null, null)

Comment: Well, nice to hear. ;-) If you need anything just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE function fnGetToInvoiceLoads (@TruckID int, @ClientID int, @OpdrachtID int, @OpcID int, @VertrekIDs varchar(max), @BestemmingIDs varchar(max), @CarIDs varchar(max)) 
    RETURNS @Table table --define @table here
    ( 
       RitChecked bit,
       RitID int, 
       ClientID int
    ) 
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Table
        SELECT <some data>

        RETURN
    END
```